# Updated Mac OS X Java broke appengine development server

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, macos, google-eclipse-plugin

I recently updated OS X 10.6.6 as recommended by Software Update: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4562

Now, even new appengine projects created with the eclipse plugin are broken.  The jetty dev server starts, and then terminates after the info message that the server is running.  There's no error information.

Ugh.

A gwt-only project created with the plugin works fine.  The jetty server starts up and happily serves the application.

My question is, I guess, how I can get more information about what's going wrong, and ultimately how can I fix this?  Even starting a project with the previous version of the jre does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem; see, for example [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/530422/GWT/SnowLeopard-Eclipse-GWT-GAE-Java). The link leads to a workaround.

Comment: The workaround is to install OpenJDK.  Seems to be working for me so far, though it's noticeably slower.

Comment: There's a better workaround now, using Pacify to install the old JDK.