# GWT Hosted Mode not working in Eclipse Helios on Mac

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, macos, gwt

I'm trying to run the shell 'new GWT' project in hosted mode through Eclipse with no luck.

The server starts but immediately shuts down before I can do anything. Here is the full console output:

```
2011-04-11 22:20:09.415 java[546:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2011-04-11 22:20:09.416 java[546:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed /Users/me/Documents/workspace/Game/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed /Users/me/Documents/workspace/Game/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

It says that the server is running and the URL is there under the development tab, but the red box indicating a running application/server is already off.

Here are my specs:

- Mac OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.7
- Eclipse Helios
- GWT 2.2.0 and associated plugins in Eclipse

A Google search shows that there were issues with 64 bit Java 6 but this was fixed in GWT 2.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Frustrating, I know! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315849/updated-mac-os-x-java-broke-appengine-development-server

Comment: Crap, sorry for not seeing that thread before. I tried to search and everything. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: No worries - I searched/debugged for an hour and still managed to miss the google issue post.  Glad I could help!

Comment: I was doing the same. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac put out a Java update that broke the dev server.  You can use Pacify to roll back the update until they, I don't know, do "something" about it.

You want answer 39 at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712#c39

Comment: Thank you! I did a search first but did not see that thread. Hopefully we get a proper fix soon. Already back on Java 6 update 22 and having no problems!